# addEventListener keydown not working in Chrome when progress bar is selected

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Suddenly spacebar stopped working (play or pause playback) when you click progress bar and it's active element.

I can't get it to work even using addEventListener with keydown.

Below is code to test it. When you click on progress bar and hit any key it should log target in console. It's working fine in Firefox but not in Chrome. Just like progress bar wasn't part of document.

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', controlVideo);  
function controlVideo(e) {    
  console.log(e.target);  
}
```

```html
<video src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" controls></video>
```

Chrome version 118.0.5993.89

Comment: The codesnippet is working  as expected in edge, probally its a  chrome restriction, you should check the releases notes and accesibility notes on chrome developer site

Comment: I have Edge 118.0.2088.57 and it behaves just like Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for quick workaround solution you can use Plyr library.
It's lightweight and spacebar works again in newest Chrome and Edge.

```js
const player = new Plyr('#video');
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.7.8/plyr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.7.8/plyr.js"></script>
<video id="video" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" controls></video>
```